# Clear all sort fields VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I am trying to sort data through excel VBA but it is already sorted by a different header.  How would I clear all the sort fields before I set the new one? I have tried `Sort.SortFields.Clear` but it hasn't worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code I'm using:

```
 Sheet9.Activate

Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(1, "J").Value = "InternalID"
Set rng2 = FindHeader("CLIENT NAME", Sheet9.Name)


Count = 1

Sheet9.Cells.Select

With Sheet9.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng2, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: Are you sure they aren't cleared? They aren't a filter so the values won't go back to their old position, but the sort fields will be clear.

Comment: Maybe you are using a filter too? In that case you might want to use .ShowAllData in such way: Sheet9.ShowAllData.

Comment: Ok. It is clearing them. But it gives me a sort reference not valid error when I try to apply it. I have updated the question with all the code I am using.

Comment: You're missing a `.SetRange` call.

Comment: maybe the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add) can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Your_Range_Value").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

I did this for every column that has a sort field and it clears them out. Where Field:=X is the column number in your range that you want to clear.

This is what I have in my Workbook. Sheet1 is code name of sheet, and rng is string representing the range value ("B4:G1500")

```
' Clear all filters 
Sheet1.Range(rng).AutoFilter Field:=1 
Sheet1.Range(rng).AutoFilter Field:=2
Sheet1.Range(rng).AutoFilter Field:=3
Sheet1.Range(rng).AutoFilter Field:=4
Sheet1.Range(rng).AutoFilter Field:=5
Sheet1.Range(rng).AutoFilter Field:=6
```